# Convert CSV to array using d3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am trying to convert a CSV file

```
Year,Make,Model,Length
1997,Ford,E350,2.34
2000,Mercury,Cougar,2.38
```

to get the resulting

```
[
  {"Year": "1997", "Make": "Ford", "Model": "E350", "Length": "2.34"},
  {"Year": "2000", "Make": "Mercury", "Model": "Cougar", "Length": "2.38"}
]
```

I am checking the website of mbostock: 
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV

```
var dataset = []
d3.csv(link, function(data) {
    dataset = data;
});
```

Can we get global variable from asynchronous functions ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. The code you've posted should achieve exactly what you want.

Comment: I think that his question is: how to get the informations in the csv from the first code to the second. The asnwer is that d3 parses the information that way when you load the csv with the callback function automatically. Each row will be parsed that way so if you call for example console.log(data.Year[0]) it should print out 1997.